# Scala replace Seq of keys with Values

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a seq in Scala = `(a1, b1, c1, d1)`
and a `Map [(a1, "Hello"), (b1, "Bye"), (c1, "Down"), (d1, "Over")]`

I want to get a Seq by replacing keys with values and get Final `Seq (Hello, Bye, Down, Over)`
in Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala's `map` should do the job. In case some keys could be missing from the map, you can use `collect` instead.

```
val a1 = 1;val b1 = 2;val c1 =3;val d1 = 4

val s1 = Seq(a1, b1, c1, d1)
val s2 = Seq(a1, 10, b1, c1, d1)
val m = Map((a1, "Hello"), (b1, "Bye"), (c1, "Down"), (d1, "Over"))

s1 map m        //res0: Seq[String] = List(Hello, Bye, Down, Over)
s2 collect m    //res1: Seq[String] = List(Hello, Bye, Down, Over)
```

Comment: I am really interested in knowing the reasons behind the downvote since I genuinely want to post correct answers and remove or edit the ones that are wrong/not useful. I understand such explanations are not always supplied and that's Ok. But why flagging a comment asking for an explanation on downvote? It was not rude, abusive, or conversational.